# Store a Cookie if Server Referrer is a specific website - PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, http-headers, referrer

I would like to redirect a user to an 'Alert Page' if they come to my new site **from** my old site. **Only on one occasion, however.** Every other time after that they would carry on to my new site unhindered.

Here is my current code for detecting the old site as the referer and redirecting:

```
<?php

if (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "www.myoldsite.com")){

    header ("Location: /alert.html");

}

?>
```

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it.

```
$cond =    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        && false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "www.myoldsite.com")
        && (   !isset($_COOKIE['alert_shown'])
            || ($_COOKIE['alert_shown']!=1)
           );

if ($cond){
    // set the cookie for 1 year.
    setcookie('alert_shown', 1, time()+3600*24*365, '/', "www.mycurrentsite.com");
    header ("Location: /showalert.html");
}
```

Points to be noted.

- `isset` should be used and its good practice
- Such cookies should be set for long time (1 year. 20 year is also okay). Because you dont want to show this alert again to user.

Comment: Out of curiosity, the snippet `isset($_COOKIE['alert_shown']) && (!$_COOKIE['alert_shown'])` -- does this mean if cookie set and if cookie doesn't exist?

Comment: @mcgarriers No, I didn't mean that. I meant if cookie `alert_shown` exists by `isset($_COOKIE['alert_shown'])` and the value of alert_shown is false or non true value by `(!$_COOKIE['alert_shown'])`. In the setcookie you'll notice I have set the value `1` so later I just check if its not 1. It could also be written as `($_COOKIE['alert_shown']!=1)`

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) I will try this out in a sec and report back.

Comment: How do I know if my Cookie is being set? When I do `var_dump($_COOKIE)` I get: `array(5) {
  ["PHPSESSID"]=>
  string(26) "au6crpm7l68qn0tk1dt7ur4177"
  ["__utma"]=>
  string(55) "250370326.1198857825.1329833613.1330340178.1330423521.7"
  ["__utmb"]=>
  string(25) "250370326.9.10.1330423521"
  ["__utmc"]=>
  string(9) "250370326"
  ["__utmz"]=>
  string(95) "250370326.1329833613.1.1.utmcsr=myoldsite.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/"
}`

Comment: For the record, my $cond seems to be failing even though I'm clicking a link from 'www.myoldsite.com'.

Comment: Thanks again. Will take a look now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your questions is odd because it contains the answer!

You already defined the logic of your code : you want to show a message and add a cookie to a user if she comes from a specific website (old yours) and has no cookie.

Here's the logic :

```
if (user referer url = "your old website" AND cookie_remember is null) then
    add cookie "cookie_remember"
    show a message (in that case, redirect to a specific page)
end if
```

For your code, your just missing the cookie part

```
if (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "www.myoldsite.com") && !isset ($_CCOKIE['alerted']){
    set_cookie('alerted', true);
    header ("Location: /alert.html");
}
```